# Prolog Query returning H128

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

In the query below, firstly I'm getting `X = H128`, where does that come from? Also why is it returning yes? Is it because the variable `X` is actually not defined and we are testing for that condition?

```
?- not(X==3).
X = H128 
yes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is using an uninstantiated variable (X).
When checking whether X is instantiated with the term 3 it (X==3) it fails because X is uninstantiated.

Therefore, not(X==3) will succeed as the prolog engine cannot prove X==3.
Your prolog interpreter is thus returning 'yes' (due to the negation as failure approach of the interpreter), and X remains uninstantiated.

That is why the interpreter shows X = H128, where H128 is a dummy uninstantiated variable.

Answer (score 3):

What was your original intention? It could be that you wanted to state that `X` is not equal to 3. For inequality many Prolog systems offer `dif/2`:

```
?- dif(X,3).
   dif(X,3).
```

In this query we ask for values for `X` that are not equal to 3. So which values are not equal? Actually, quite a lot: Think of `1`, `2`, the term `3+3`, `c`, the list `[2,3,4]` and many more. So giving a concrete answer like `X = 4` would exclude many other valid answers. The answer here is however: The query holds for all `X` that are not equal to 3. The actual evaluation is therefore delayed to a later moment.

```
?- dif(X,3), X = 3.
   false.
```

Here we got in a situation where `X` got the value 3 - which does not hold.

```
?- dif(X,3), X = 4.
   X = 4.
```

And here a concrete valid value is accepted, and the restriciton `dif(4,3)` is removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is because the variable `X` is not bound by the first goal, `not(X==3)`.  Actually the `not/1` metapredicate can never produce a binding, even if it succeeds.  That's because success of `not` means the inner goal fails.  Note that `not(X=3)` would fail because `X=3` can succeed when `X` is free (and can be bound to value 3).