# Not equal and not unify in Prolog

Tags: prolog

What is the difference between A \= B and not(A==B) in Prolog?

I found this http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5 
and this wiki page 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Built-in_predicates 
but it didn't help me since there is no clarification to the difference, nor short meaning for \=.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested to read also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523608/logical-not-in-prolog/8523825#8523825)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6686911) answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`A \= B` is equivalent to `not (A = B)`

So lets compare `=/2` and `==/2` first; from the swi-prolog manual:

> ?Term1 = ?Term2
>       Unify Term1 with Term2. True if the unification succeeds
>
> @Term1 == @Term2
>       True if Term1 is equivalent to Term2.

Notice that `=/2` tries to unify the terms and if it succeeds it's true while `==/2` just performs a check:

```
?- X = 1.
X = 1.
(implicit true.)
```

while

```
?- X == 1.
false.
```

and also:

```
?- X = Y.
X = Y.

?- X == Y.
false.
```

now, `not/1` will invert the result and be true if `=/2` or `==/2` was false.
for`==/2` there is nothing complicated; if the terms were equivalent now it will return false otherwise true.
for `=/2` you should remember that all unifications will be temporary:

```
?- \+ (\+ X = 1), print(X).
_G399
true.
```

(`_G399` indicates that `X` is non-instantiated)

Comment: But what about not(A==B)? From my short experience there is a difference between it & /= since my code works as expected with not and does not with \=.

Comment: @VitaliPom sorry if i was not clear; the difference between `not(A==B)` and `(A\=B)` is the same as between `A==B` and `A=B`: `not A==B` will true if the terms are not the same even if they can be unified while `\=` will return false

Comment: @VitaliPom you can view unification as a generalisation of assignment: `X=1` X is unified with 1 and now it's 1. `[X,Y] = [1,2]` X is 1, Y is 2. `[X,2] = [4,Y]` X is 4, Y is 2. `1+X = Y+(Z+3)` Y is 1, X is Z+3.